# Detect the when the youtube video starts playing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

How Can using the youtube api and javascript detect the time it takes for the first image of the video to play after clicking the play. Therefore I can measure the time it takes and the amount it prebuffers before it can play

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#Events .... Google are quite adept at developing documentation for these things. Also some demonstration of work attempted would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are event handlers in the API itself as documented here :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#Events

Notably : `onYouTubePlayerReady(playerid)`

Therefore you could try something like :

```
 function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    player = document.getElementById("playerID");
    player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "callMeWhenStateChange");
 }
```

The `callMeWhenStateChange` is then fired on the state change, so you want to listen for state `1` I believe.. Again refer to documentation.

```
function callMeWhenStateChange(state) {
    if(state == 1)
       console.log("Current state is playing : " + state);
 }
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks it does I just was not sure if the buffered state is set before playing or not.

Comment: @user3019025 the buffering state is : `3 (buffering)`